# Cannot read .sign of undefined error being thrown with Fastify

Tags: node.js, jwt, fastify

I am creating my server the following way:

```
const createServer = options => {
  const { logSeverity } = options;

  const server = Fastify({
    ignoreTrailingSlash: true
  });


  server.listen(5000, err => {
    if (err) {
      server.log.error(err);
      console.log(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  });

  server.register(AutoLoad, {
    dir: path.join(__dirname, "api", "routes")
  });

  server.register(jwt, {
    secret: nconf.get("secrets.jwt")
  });
};
```

And in one of my modules at `./some/child/path/signToken.js`, I do:

```
const nconf = require("nconf");
const jwt = require("fastify-jwt");

const signToken = payload => {
  fastify.jwt.sign(payload, nconf.get("secrets.jwt"), (err, token) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const response = {
      userId: payload.user._id,
      username: payload.user.username,
      token
    };

    return response;
  });
};

module.exports = { signToken };
```

Which throws an error, `Cannot read property 'sign' of undefined`.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-jwt),

```
This will decorate your fastify instance with the standard jsonwebtoken methods
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is this perhaps not possible because I am creating a server, and server is my fastify instance? Would I then have to import `server` somehow?

Comment: asking this is silly but have you imorted **const fastify = require('fastify')**

Comment: I have before, got rid of it because it still throws undefined either way, not silly at all

Comment: i think this is a good examle here in npm [ https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-jwt ] .might be there is problem in utilization of module

Comment: how do you load `signToken.js`? Right now the `fastify.jwt.sign` variable does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You are starting your server with

```
server.listen(5000...
```

Before registering your plugins.

According to [the fastify docs](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Getting-Started/#loading-order-of-your-plugins)  the proper order is:

1. plugins (from the fastify ecosystem)
2. your plugins (your custom plugins)
3. decorators
4. hooks and middlewares
5. your services

This should happen before calling fastify.listen().